# DocumentBuilder - how to turn off case sensitivity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder to parse xml, which is unfortunately not quite to spec - some tags have different case. Is there a property i can set in DocumentBUilder so that it parses tags with disregard to case? Thx.

PS. I cant just use another library as its a mobile environment.

Comment: I'm going to guess that no there is not, as that would be a flagrant violation of the XML spec. Maybe you could filter the document before hand, and force all tags to lower case?

Answer (score 0):

If the input is valid XML (that is, if start and end tags always match, ie. `<p>...</p>` or `<P> ... </p>` but never `<p>...</P>`) then you can process the data using XML tools such as XSLT. If the data isn't well-formed XML then you will need to use non-XML tools, e.g. Perl scripts. If the data has HTML-like characteristics then a tool like JTidy or TagSoup might turn it into something useful.

Answer (score -1):

You could call `String.toLowerCase()` and then parse the new string

Comment: it will change "<p>...</P>" to "<p>...</p>" (note the lower case P in the end tag)

Comment: <p>HeLo</P>   =>  <p>helo</p>      not acceptable. Data is mangled.